# How to store object references in elements as custom atributes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ckeditor

I have a number of dynamic generated widgets in the editor content (online app) and need to store their reference in clickable buttons to retrieve custom data attributes at a later time when one of the button is clicked.

I thought maybe it's going this way :

```
var template = '<div class="simplebox">' +
   '<div class="simplebox-marker"><input class="timeMarker" type="button" value='+time+'></input></div >' +
   '<div  class="simplebox-title"><p>title here ...</p></div >' +
   '<div class="simplebox-content"><p></p>content here ... </div>'</div>';

...     
widget = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( template, editor.document );
timeMarkerButton.setAttribute('data-widget', widget);  // widget object ref
...
```

But in the source code all I got is this :

```
data-widget="[object Object]"
```

- Is this a case of `allowedContent` filtering ? If so how to allow it ?
- If not, how to store an object reference anyway ?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with CKEditor or Advanced Content Filter. Basically, an element attribute is a string so your object is being stringified (by calling `.toString()` on it).

There are couple of solutions:

- If it's a plain object you can override that method and use `JSON.stringify()`. You can also stringify it manually before using `setAttribute()`.
- You can use custom data (similar to jQuery's [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) AFAIK) you can use [`element.setCustomData()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.domObject-method-setCustomData) which can store any object, but it doesn't set an attribute, so the value will not be preserved in your data.
- Finally, if you need to store those objects in your data, you will need to create a hash of them and store only keys in attributes, not the whole objects. As I can see you tried to store a widget in an attribute, so you can simply store its [id](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-property-id) and access it later through [`editor.widgets.instance`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-property-instances).

Comment: 3 more questions to your third proposal. How to get widget id's , how to store them as custom attributes and how to access them later ?

Comment: You have really no shame. I love to help people, but I will not answer your questions. You haven't accepted any answer to your questions, you were rude, you didn't spend a minimum amount of time googling...

Comment: Thanks for your reproaches. They are simply not true. I spend hours to google and to read about widgets at CKEditor API Sites. When I follow your link to 'ID' I can read that 'id' is the widgets unique ID. Just a great, very helpful explanation if you finally need to know how to retrieve that ID. The same with how to access widgets. So I finally asked you 3 days later back with the hope that you could send me a link with a sample. I have seen this a lot in this forum. Whats bad about it ? This is the best way to proceed and help. What do you mean with "accepted any answer" ?

Comment: Maybe I incorrectly read this, but really... In your code I see that you have a widget instance, so the only thing you need to do is to get [`widget.id`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-property-id). You want to say that you haven't tried this? The same with setting custom data - I linked to [`element.setCustomData()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.domObject-method-setCustomData), I mentioned `setAttribute()`. Do you want to say that you haven't found complementary `getCustomData()` and `getAttribute()`? I can hardly believe this.

Comment: Anyway, asking questions is good. I like to work with devs who do that. But I need to see that first they did their homework. As for accepting any answer - none of the answers given to your questions were accepted by you, even your own one. This was already mentioned to you by other user in another question, I'm just repeating.

Comment: My widget code is like above.  Then I registrate the widget (as you recommended)   editor.widgets.initOn( );   
Next line is this  var widgetId = markerWidget.id;  But the widgetID is "undefined". So what to do ? Banging my head against the wall or asking core devs again ?  AGAIN : What do you mean with "accepted". I do not no this. Maybe you give a concret answer and help. I am not an SO professional. Okay ? And finally I guess I do my homework very well.

Comment: After try&error I got it. But not as you wrote " widget.id"  , that is just wrong. I got it now by "widget.getId()".  So my recommendation is: Don't shoot before you are not sure that you are in a raid.

Comment: @Ben, regarding: *'What do you mean with "accepted". I do not no this.'*: see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers & http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer & http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 I have explained this to you multiple times in a helpful polite way, from different relevant unbiased angles (like on your self-answered question), referencing both official and community SO rules/guidelines URL's, *before* you placed above comment. But you responded you 'don't accept answers'. If you are hindered by a language-barrier, try running these links through google translate.

Comment: @GitaarLAB would be great to stop your engagement to educate me. I am not hindered by a language-barrier, but obvioulsly you like to play the watchdog lurking at my account. Just leave it. When I have enough time I will study your links. Gracias

Comment: Priceless...... @Ben: You asked a question *twice* above: `What do you mean with "accepted any answer" ?` & `AGAIN : What do you mean with "accepted"` and I gave `a concret answer` to that question, providing 3 official links. Then you respond by `would be great to stop your engagement to educate me`? Well.. why didn't you say so in the beginning, then a lot of time could have been re-directed *to people who do want to be educated*. Wish granted! Random parting tip: Internet is just like being out in the open, expect to be caught if you drop your pants.

Comment: Hey man (or woman dont know). I asked twice because I did not get an answer from Reinmar on this. He made a reproach but did not explain how to solve. Okay ? So finish this story now. Get out of this issue unless you have a concrete solution for my initial question.